# Extracting third column in an efficient way using perl

Tags: regex, perl

This Perl code gives the output as three.

```
echo one two three four | perl -pe 's/(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+).*/$3/'
```

Is there any elegant solution to cut short this lengthy repetitive regular expression?

Answer (score 7):

Perl has an autosplit command line option ([see perlrun, -a](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches))

```
echo one two three four | perl -lane 'print $F[2]'
```

EDIT: added `-l` per Vijay

Comment: you can remove the "\n" by adding -l flag `perl -lane 'print $F[2]'`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the interval quantify `{m,n}` to indication repetition:

```
$ echo one two three four | perl -pe 's/((\w+)\s){2}(\w+).*/$3/'
three
```

So for the 100th column you do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/((\w+)\s){99}(\w+).*/$100/'
```

However I wouldn't suggest you do this as there a much easier ways to print single fields i.e with `cut`:

```
$ echo one tow three fout | cut -f3 -d' '  
three
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat test 
dsadasd dasdsad 3333 4rrff 
$ perl -lane 'print $F[2]' test 
3333
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
cut -f3 -d" "
```

or

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

or

```
perl -plane 's/.*/$F[2]/'
```

Comment: I believe -p and -n are mutually exclusive options (-p overrides -n).